# quantmod ttr getSymbol & quotes hardcoded

Tags: r, quantmod, rserve

I am a quite new with R programming and now developing  a system that is suppose to interact with R. **My question is :**

How to get quotes from hard coded from the scripts rather than from various sources like “yahoo” “google” etc?

**Why do I need quotes hard coded in the script?**

I am using Rserve as my downstream system, the main system does fetching of data and will perform other portfolio checks then it makes a call to `R-TTR-quantmod` packages for calculation of financial numbers. So I don’t want R to refetch those quotes so I want the quotes to be hardcoded and sent from my system to `Rserve` where it gets executed and results is returned from there. This way my code would rely on standard calculation on R and user can focus on other business logic.

**Why am I not using csv file approach ?**

I am in a realtime system and file io would take huge time and would slow down my system.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
library(quantmod)

library(TTR)
```

*Pull S&P500 index data from Yahoo! Finance*

```
getSymbols("^RIL", from="2000-01-01", to="2008-12-07")
```

*Calculate the RSI indicator*

```
rsi <- RSI(Cl(RIL),2)
```

So this is what I need:

- Rather than calling `getSymbol` I would like to pass the data as a
  variable in the script.
- I assume the data may be very large at time or very small at times.
- So what should I do in this scenario?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you might find `dput` to be of use. It returns the code of an R data structure that you can put into scripts to replicate a data item.

Comment: If the data is already there, as an `xts` object, you can use it directly. For instance, if the data is in a variable `x`, you can just use `rsi <- RSI(x,2)` or `rsi <- RSI(Cl(x),2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working on some code to use load/save to cache xts objects. The code is trivial:

```
getSymbols("^RIL", from="2000-01-01", to="2008-12-07")
save(RIL,file="cache/RIL.rdata")
```

Then in your other script that does the analysis:

```
load("cache/RIL.rdata")
rsi <- RSI(Cl(RIL),2)
```

As an added bonus the .rdata files are gzipped.

Some stats: Exhibit 1

My previous approach had 1 minute bars, as one csv file per day. 303 files, summing to 12MB, loaded into a 86,590 row XTS object took 5.64s (elapsed; the user time was 5.34s).

The .rdata file is 2.8MB and takes 0.056s.

Exhibit 2:

First approach: Running RSI freshly on the data (as a pre-cursor to another calculation).
Second approach: Have another offline process run RSI on the data, and cache it to an .rdata file.

Loading the RSI file worked out 3 times quicker than calculating the RSI data freshly.

Warning: in my timing tests I used a loop where it is created/saved on pass 1, and then loaded on passes 2 to 20. It was the latter loading I was timing. So it would've been fresh in any OS file caches.